# iText: Cell with Image doesn't apply Rowspan

Tags: java, image, html-table, itext

I have a table (2 x 2).
If I add a Phrase as cell in the first cell with rowspan 2, it works. But if I use an Image as cell, rowspan never apply.

```
    float[] rowwidths2 = {0.6f,0.4f};
    PdfPTable felsoegyharmad = new PdfPTable(rowwidths2);
    felsoegyharmad.setWidthPercentage(100);
    PdfPCell kepcell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("image place", fontAlap));
    kepcell.setRowspan(2);
    felsoegyharmad.addCell(kepcell);
    felsoegyharmad.addCell(new Phrase("1", fontAlap));
    felsoegyharmad.addCell(new Phrase("2", fontAlap));
```

Code above is works as advertise.
But this code under is never rowspanned:

```
    PdfPCell kepcell = new PdfPCell();
    kepcell.addElement(Image.getInstance(path));
    kepcell.setRowspan(2);
    felsoegyharmad.addCell(kepcell);
    felsoegyharmad.addCell(new Phrase("1", fontAlap));
    felsoegyharmad.addCell(new Phrase("2", fontAlap));
```

How can I put this image into the first column but in height as two rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you wonder why nobody is answering your question. That's simple: the problem you describe can not be reproduced. I have taken your code snippet, and I have created the following standalone example:

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
PdfPCell imageCell = new PdfPCell();
imageCell.addElement(Image.getInstance(IMG));
imageCell.setRowspan(2);
table.addCell(imageCell);
table.addCell(new Phrase("1"));
table.addCell(new Phrase("2"));
```

For the full source code, see [ImageRowspan](https://git.itextsupport.com/projects/I5JS/repos/sandbox/browse/src/main/java/sandbox/tables/ImageRowspan.java)

The resulting PDF looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, the table has two columns and two rows. The first cell (the one with the image) spans two rows. You can download [cmp_image_rowspan.pdf](https://git.itextsupport.com/projects/I5JS/repos/sandbox/browse/cmpfiles/tables/cmp_image_rowspan.pdf) from out git repository.